# Updating post_meta in WordPress through XML-RPC

Tags: ruby, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am currently working on a project that involves scraping data from over 300 static pages and transferring that data into a WordPress site. I have set up various custom fields with the Simple Fields (http://simple-fields.com/) plugin, and have a basic XML-RPC connection working. Below is what I am using to test injecting custom posts (written in Ruby):

```
connection = XMLRPC::Client.new_from_uri "http://localhost:8888/xmlrpc.php"
username   = "admin"
password   = "password"
test_post  = {
  :post_type   => "custom_property",
  :post_status => "draft",
  :post_title  => "test post!",
  :post_meta   => {
    :_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_3_numInSet_0 => "test"
  }
}
puts connection.call("wp.newPost", 1, username, password, test_post)
```

I have tried :custom_fields in place of :post_meta but still to no avail. I can't seem to be able to update the custom fields that have been created through Simple Fields.

If anyone has any suggestions on what to do, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: This problem was solved by extending the XML-RPC functions using this article: http://kovshenin.com/2010/custom-xml-rpc-methods-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite tricky to figure out the structure of the Wordpress post. If it is a custom field you want to post in, you should use the format below:

```
'custom_fields' => [{'key' => 'something', 'value' => 'something else'}]
```

If it is custom taxonomy, use this:

```
'terms' => {
            'custom_type' => [value],
            'custom_something' => ['array_item','array_item']
        }
```

For terms you always need to put the value into an array even if it's just one item. Hope it helped.